# react-refetch : "fetch must be a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm using React v15.3.2, Redux and [React-refetch](https://github.com/heroku/react-refetch) v1.0.0-beta.10 and I would like to fetch data before rendering the page. Below my code :

**Layout component**

```
/* Import libraries */
export default class extends Component {
    ...
    render() {
        return (
          <Provider store={ this.store }>
              { this.renderComponent() } 
              // In this case, I would render User component(see code below)
          </Provider>
        )
     }
 }
```

**User component**

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect, PromiseState} from 'react-refetch'
import Layout from 'layout'
class User extends Layout {
    renderComponent() {
        const {userFetch} = this.props;

        if (userFetch.pending) {
            return <p>Pending</p>
          } else if (userFetch.rejected) {
            return <p>Rejected</p>
          } else if (userFetch.fulfilled) {
            return <p>Fulfilled</p>
          }
        }
}

export default connect(props => ({
  userFetch: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`
}))(User)
```

When I run the server, I get this error : `Invariant Violation: fetch must be a function. Instead received a undefined.` Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**PS**: When I put static data in `renderComponent` and update `export default connect...` to `export default User`, it works!

**SOLUTION :**

1 - in `User` component, put `<ListUsers />` in renderComponent()

2 - Install `isomorphic-fetch` and add `ListUsers` as component :

```
// Import librairies
require('isomorphic-fetch');
class ListUsers extends Component {
    // Put the body of renderComponent() here 
}
export default connect(...)
```

I don't know if it's the best solution but it works for me.

Comment: Do you get that error in every browser?

Comment: @azium yes, the same error...

Comment: Hmm, just to be on the safe side, doing `console.log(fetch)` prints `function fetch()` right?

Comment: When I put `console.log(fetch)` for the first time, I got `function fetch(){ native code }` but when I tried to stop et rerun the server I got the same error `Invariant Violation: fetch must be a function. Instead received a undefined`

Answer (score -3):

```
export default connect(props => ({
   userFetch: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`
}))(User)
```

I think there is an error in your code here: isn't it supposed to be:

```
 export default connect(props) => ({
    userFetch: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`
 })(User)
```

See how I moved the parentheses?

Comment: Nope, that's not even correct syntax... `connect(...)` returns a function so his original syntax was valid.